# Xcode Loop for FB handle url using application:openURL:options using using url scheme

Tags: ionic-framework, url-scheme, deeplink, cordova-ios

**Problem**

App crash after using an url scheme "correctly" set in the project plist.

**Wrong behaviour**

When we click on a button with the following code

```
window.location.replace('booking://');
```

App is correctly opened, but from Xcode log i can see a loop about cordova.plugin.facebook4. Here below an extract:

```
    com.package.myapp [1244:303605] <Warning>: Please set a value for FacebookAutoLogAppEventsEnabled. Set the flag to TRUE if you want to collect app install, app launch and in-app purchase events automatically. To request user consent before collecting data, set the flag value to FALSE, then change to TRUE once user consent is received. Learn more: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/getting-started-app-events-ios#disable-auto-events.
com.package.myapp [1244:303605] <Warning>: You haven't set a value for FacebookAdvertiserIDCollectionEnabled. Set the flag to TRUE if you want to collect Advertiser ID for better advertising and analytics results. To request user consent before collecting data, set the flag value to FALSE, then change to TRUE once user consent is received. Learn more: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/getting-started-app-events-ios#disable-auto-events.
com.package.myapp [1244:303673]  - <AppMeasurement>[I-ACS036002] Analytics screen reporting is enabled. Call +[FIRAnalytics setScreenName:setScreenClass:] to set the screen name or override the default screen class name. To disable screen reporting, set the flag FirebaseScreenReportingEnabled to NO (boolean) in the Info.plist
com.package.myapp [1244:303605] You've implemented -[<UIApplicationDelegate> application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:], but you still need to add "remote-notification" to the list of your supported UIBackgroundModes in your Info.plist.
com.package.myapp [1244:303605] Apache Cordova native platform version 4.5.3 is starting.
com.package.myapp [1244:303605] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
com.package.myapp [1244:303605] Using UIWebView
com.package.myapp [1244:303605] [CDVTimer][console] 0.079036ms
com.package.myapp [1244:303605] [CDVTimer][handleopenurl] 0.090003ms
com.package.myapp [1244:303605] Unlimited access to network resources
com.package.myapp [1244:303605] [CDVTimer][intentandnavigationfilter] 1.543999ms
com.package.myapp [1244:303605] [CDVTimer][gesturehandler] 0.080943ms
com.package.myapp [1244:303605] [CDVTimer][splashscreen] 46.319962ms
com.package.myapp [1244:303605] CDVIonicKeyboard: no resize
com.package.myapp [1244:303605] CDVIonicKeyboard: WARNING!!: Keyboard plugin works better with WK
com.package.myapp [1244:303605] [CDVTimer][keyboard] 1.255035ms
com.package.myapp [1244:303605] [CDVTimer][file] 2.826929ms
com.package.myapp [1244:303605] [CDVTimer][statusbar] 6.577969ms
com.package.myapp [1244:303605] Starting Facebook Connect plugin
com.package.myapp [1244:303605] [CDVTimer][facebookconnectplugin] 0.175953ms
com.package.myapp [1244:303605] Starting Firebase plugin
com.package.myapp [1244:303605] [CDVTimer][firebaseplugin] 0.172973ms
com.package.myapp [1244:303605] [CDVTimer][TotalPluginStartup] 59.953928ms
com.package.myapp [1244:303605] GoogleService-Info.plist found, setup: [FIRApp configureWithOptions]
com.package.myapp [1244:303605] [Crashlytics] Version 3.10.7 (130)
com.package.myapp [1244:303694] 5.7.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Analytics v.50101000 started
com.package.myapp [1244:303682] [NetworkInfo] Signal strength query returned error: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=13 "Permission denied", descriptor: <CTServiceDescriptor 0x2835a7fe0, domain=1, instance=1>
com.package.myapp [1244:303691] [Crashlytics:Crash:Reports] Packaged report with id 'a3e7393c82294b67b6691b34a3de8b5b' for submission
com.package.myapp [1244:303605] FB Hybrid app events cannot be enabled, this feature requires WKWebView
com.package.myapp [1244:303694] 5.7.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see %url hidden by me%)
com.package.myapp [1244:303605] Resetting plugins due to page load.
com.package.myapp [1244:303694] 5.7.0 - [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM001000] FIRMessaging Remote Notifications proxy enabled, will swizzle remote notification receiver handlers. If you'd prefer to manually integrate Firebase Messaging, add "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled" to your Info.plist, and set it to NO. Follow the instructions at:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#method_swizzling_in_firebase_messaging
to ensure proper integration.
com.package.myapp [1244:303694] 5.7.0 - [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM002023] The object <AppDelegate: 0x2835846c0> does not respond to -messaging:didReceiveRegistrationToken:. Please implement -messaging:didReceiveRegistrationToken: to be provided with an FCM token.
com.package.myapp [1244:303693] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C4.1:2][0x10323cef0] get output frames failed, state 8196
com.package.myapp [1244:303693] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C4.1:2][0x10323cef0] get output frames failed, state 8196
com.package.myapp [1244:303693] TIC Read Status [4:0x0]: 1:57
com.package.myapp [1244:303693] TIC Read Status [4:0x0]: 1:57
com.package.myapp [1244:303692] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C3.1:2][0x10323b5a0] get output frames failed, state 8196
com.package.myapp [1244:303692] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C3.1:2][0x10323b5a0] get output frames failed, state 8196
com.package.myapp [1244:303692] TIC Read Status [3:0x0]: 1:57
com.package.myapp [1244:303692] TIC Read Status [3:0x0]: 1:57
com.package.myapp [1244:303605] Connected to FCM.
com.package.myapp [1244:303605] InstanceID token: %token hidden by me%
com.package.myapp [1244:303677] [Fabric] failed to download settings Error Domain=FABNetworkError Code=-5 "(null)" UserInfo={status_code=403, type=2, request_id=%id hidden by me%, content_type=application/json; charset=utf-8}
com.package.myapp [1244:303605] THREAD WARNING: ['NetworkStatus'] took '30.950195' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
com.package.myapp [1244:303605] Finished load of: file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/5D9D0E7E-316E-40E7-8C14-43891ACBFE1D/com.package.myapp .app/www/index.html#/login
com.package.myapp [1244:303605] Disconnected from FCM
com.package.myapp [1244:303605] FRAMEWORK IONIC PAUSE
com.package.myapp [1244:303605] STATUS OF APP.PAUSE false
com.package.myapp [1244:303605] FB handle url using application:openURL:options: booking://
com.package.myapp [1244:303605] FB handle url using application:openURL:options: booking://
com.package.myapp [1244:303605] FB handle url using application:openURL:options: booking://
com.package.myapp [1244:303605] FB handle url using application:openURL:options: booking://
com.package.myapp [1244:303605] FB handle url using application:openURL:options: booking://
com.package.myapp [1244:303605] FB handle url using application:openURL:options: booking://
com.package.myapp [1244:303605] FB handle url using application:openURL:options: booking://
com.package.myapp [1244:303605] FB handle url using application:openURL:options: booking://
com.package.myapp [1244:303605] FB handle url using application:openURL:options: booking://
com.package.myapp [1244:303605] FB handle url using application:openURL:options: booking://
com.package.myapp [1244:303605] FB handle url using application:openURL:options: booking://
com.package.myapp [1244:303605] FB handle url using application:openURL:options: booking://
com.package.myapp [1244:303605] FB handle url using application:openURL:options: booking://
com.package.myapp [1244:303605] FB handle url using application:openURL:options: booking://
com.package.myapp [1244:303605] FB handle url using application:openURL:options: booking://
com.package.myapp [1244:303605] FB handle url using application:openURL:options: booking://
com.package.myapp [1244:303605] FB handle url using application:openURL:options: booking://
com.package.myapp [1244:303605] FB handle url using application:openURL:options: booking://
com.package.myapp [1244:303605] FB handle url using application:openURL:options: booking://
com.package.myapp [1244:303605] FB handle url using application:openURL:options: booking://
com.package.myapp [1244:303605] FB handle url using application:openURL:options: booking://
com.package.myapp [1244:303605] FB handle url using application:openURL:options: booking://
com.package.myapp [1244:303605] FB handle url using application:openURL:options: booking://
com.package.myapp [1244:303605] FB handle url using application:openURL:options: booking://
com.package.myapp [1244:303605] FB handle url using application:openURL:options: booking://
com.package.myapp [1244:303605] FB handle url using application:openURL:options: booking://
com.package.myapp [1244:303605] FB handle url using application:openURL:options: booking://
com.package.myapp [1244:303605] FB handle url using application:openURL:options: booking://
com.package.myapp [1244:303605] FB handle url using application:openURL:options: booking://
com.package.myapp [1244:303605] FB handle url using application:openURL:options: booking://
com.package.myapp [1244:303605] FB handle url using application:openURL:options: booking:// <<--- this continue until an error "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x16f74ffc0)" is shown
```

Any suggestion?
Clearly Android is working like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

We solved the problem downgrading plugin cordova-plugin-facebook4 to version 4.2.1 due to a problem introduced in last version 5.0.0.

Thanks btw to everyone.
Hope it can help!

Simon